# How can a rigged model be used multiple times in a scene?

Tags: scene, groups

I've created a rigged model and created and grouped the model and rig.

I would like to add it multiple times in a single scene. I used *File > Append selected* the group, made it local <kbd>L</kbd> and created a proxy <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>.

But I can do this only once, when I try to repeat the procedure described before nothing happens.

It works when I save the group in another file, and link two different groups into the scene.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you repeat if for the same group or a different one?

Comment: @iKlsR When I repeat it for the same file nothing happens (not even an error message), when I copy the file first say group1.blend and group2.blend then I can link two objects. This wouldn't be a good way to place a school of fish in a fishtank.

Comment: if you have already done the steps above, you wouldn't need to do it on the same file, just add a new grouped instance since the object is already in the scene.

Comment: IIRC, the rig is usually saved as a different object from the mesh? If so, just import both of them at the same time.

Comment: @iKlsR: Instancing two linked groups and making proxy of the rig in each of the group instances works.. But when posing the first proxy, the surface in the second group instance also moves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One you have imported the model. You can add it to the scene just as you would add any other object. Just open the <kbd>Space</kbd> Menu and go to *Group Instance* and you should see a new entry there for the rigged model.

[image]

Comment: thank you, it didn't work from the Space menu, but from the Main menu / Add.