# How can I independently pose Group Instances?

Tags: rigging, workflow, linked-data, groups

I would like to add two instances of a model created by [makehuman](http://www.makehuman.org/) to a scene.

After linking one model (*File/Link*) and adding a proxy <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd>. I used *Add / Group Instance* to add another instance but after that both models change pose when I make changes in pose mode.

How can both models be animated independent from each other?

This a follow-up of an earlier question [how-can-a-rigged-model-be-used-multiple-times-in-a-scene](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/201/how-can-a-rigged-model-be-used-multiple-times-in-a-scene)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Linux (have not tested on Mac) I recently used the following method to create layout for a shot that required 3 instances of a procedural rock creation rig. Then i created a proxy of the armature from each of the group instances and posed them accordingly.

[image: Reusing single asset using hard-links and instanced groups]

Starting with two folders: one containing an asset file and the other where my shot file exists. In the asset file the Rig/Geometry is grouped.

```
blend:~/demoProceduralRocks>> ls
asset/ shot1/
```

Since I want to create create a scene that should have 3 identical instances of the asset, I create hard links to the file in the shot's import folder

```
blend:~/demoProceduralRocks>> cd shot1/import/

blend:~/demoProceduralRocks/shot1/import>> ln -v ../../asset/Rock.blend Rock.instance.1.blend

blend:~/demoProceduralRocks/shot1/import>> ln -v ../../asset/Rock.blend Rock.instance.2.blend

blend:~/demoProceduralRocks/shot1/import>> ln -v ../../asset/Rock.blend Rock.instance.3.blend
```

This is how it looks after creating hard links

```
blend:~/demoProceduralRocks> ls -lirt asset/ shot1/import/
asset/:
total 172
22217836 -rw-rw-r-- 4 blend home 169297 2013-05-27 15:22 Rock.blend

shot1/import/:
total 516
22217836 -rw-rw-r-- 4 blend home 169297 2013-05-27 15:22 Rock.instance.3.blend
22217836 -rw-rw-r-- 4 blend home 169297 2013-05-27 15:22 Rock.instance.2.blend
22217836 -rw-rw-r-- 4 blend home 169297 2013-05-27 15:22 Rock.instance.1.blend
```

Then I layout the shot file by linking the groups from the hard linked files created above. Then I make a proxy of the Armature and Pose each proxy separately. ([A demo of this in action](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b_789nEl_M0))

```
blend:~/demoProceduralRocks> tree ./
./
|-- asset
|   `-- Rock.blend
`-- shot1
    |-- Layout.shot1.blend
    `-- import
        |-- Rock.instance.1.blend
        |-- Rock.instance.2.blend
        `-- Rock.instance.3.blend
```

Comment: thanks, this works also on windows `mklink /H link.blend original.blend` (+1)

Comment: Thank you for confirming about the fact that it works on Windows also. :)

Answer (score 2):

Separate the same model into different blend files. Also give different group names.

For example, you have one character, let's say the name was `char.blend`. Then save as the `char.blend` into files with different names such as `char_a.blend`, `char_b.blend`. Make sure the group also has a different name. So now, you can link both files, and both will be independent.

Comment: Thanks, that is the workaround I currently use, I looking for a method to use one single model multiple times in a scene since I edit it and add more poses.