# How to duplicate linked(external) rigged character and animate each instance independently?

Tags: rigging, linked-data

I have linked [cookie flex rig](http://cgcookie.com/blender/resource/cg-cookie-flex-rig-free-download/) by browsing to the groups folder of the rig file and then linking the character group (standard method) and not appending.
And then i did a proxy of rig by pressing "Ctrl+Alt+P" and selecting "rig" from list.
After this i do some animation and it works.

**My Problem**
But if i create another instance of the same "linked group"(charecter) and then proxy the rig
then even the first instance gets the same pose as the second one. I am not able to independently animate the two instances.

**Pls note** that i am aware of creating different files of the source rig file and renaming the groups and then instancing them back into one file. But i am not happy with this method as its crude. It create many files using more storage space. I have been using this solution though.

[image][image]

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1123/how-can-i-independently-pose-group-instances

Comment: @stacker i am aware of this work around. But it just makes the project bulky. But there should be more elegant way of doing it. I don't know how they do it in crowd simulation, but there they might be doing something that creates independent instance of same rigged character.

Comment: I wasn't able to find a better solution yet.

Comment: In the Animation Toolkit that the Flexrig was originally released with, Nathan explains this as a limit of how blender works. One external file per character is the way to make it work. Don't know if there is any plan to change this. Maybe with the new dependency graph work this can be changed?

Comment: @sambler i had missed Nathan's explanation, thanks for that. But there should some work around. How one would generate crowd ? one cant create new file for each crowd character